# EC2 Ubuntu hangs on go install

Tags: amazon-ec2, installation

I am running the golang rest api on ec2 instance which is working properly however when I make any changes in the code and run "go install" the ec2 console stops responding and I have to reboot the instance. ec2 instance is running with 4 GB ram and ubuntu 20.

Please suggest how to debug and fix the issue.

Comment: Add the `-x` command line option to the `go install` call and make sure the output it generates to its stanard error stream gets collected somewhere where you can read it. Then run it and try to make out which step hangs. That command-line option makes `go install` be (very) verbose about what it does. And while we're on it, please note that questions like this are 100% [off-topic on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and also have nothing to do with Go. [This](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/amazon-ec2) might be way more appropriate place to deal with infrastucture problems.

Comment: @kostix thanks for suggestion, may be its nothing to do with go but I am facing the issue with go install only, I have mongo, mysql, nodejs, socket etc installed and all are working properly. let me try with this if it works or post on other location you suggested. Thanks

Comment: The problem is not what you think you're facing issue with, really. The `go` tag here on SO is meant for questions related to _programming_ in Go, and your problem is definitely not one of them—it's an infrastructure problem (DevOps-class, if you wish).

Comment: I may cojure that `go install` tries to download and install some external modules, and faces some network/authentication/etc problems. That's why you need to trace what it attempts to do.

Comment: @kostix thanks for suggestion, I will check for the same if find anything.